# Why can't variables declared outside a function be used within it?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, electron, node-modules

This code should work but the error message is "Cannot deconstruct

```
const fs = require('fs');
let {  remote: { app  }  } = require('electron');  
let userDataPath = app.getPath('userData');
let filePath = path.join(userDataPath, 'preferences.json')

const readPreferences = () => {
    return JSON.parse( fs.readFileSync(filePath) )
}
const writePreferences = (inputs) => { 
    inputs && fs.writeFileSync(filePath, JSON.stringify(inputs));
}

module.exports = {readPreferences, writePreferences };
```

But if I add the all the `let` variables inside each function, the code works.

Is that normal? why does that happen.

And should be repeating those there?

I tried this in a separate demo and it all works fine:

```
// - two.js
let two = "this is something"
exports.one = () => {  
    return two
}

// - index.js
const { one } = require('./two')
let two = "anything"
console.log(one()) // -> this is something
```

Edit: This works though

```
const fs = require('fs');    
const readPreferences = () => {
let {  remote: { app  }  } = require('electron');  
let userDataPath = app.getPath('userData');
let filePath = path.join(userDataPath, 'preferences.json')
    return JSON.parse( fs.readFileSync(filePath) )
}
const writePreferences = (inputs) => { 
let {  remote: { app  }  } = require('electron');  
let userDataPath = app.getPath('userData');
let filePath = path.join(userDataPath, 'preferences.json')
    inputs && fs.writeFileSync(filePath, JSON.stringify(inputs));
}

module.exports = {readPreferences, writePreferences };
```

Comment: The only thing relevant is 'cannot deconstruct'. Go to the *specific* line, and pull that out in in a SSCCE. Try with different values for the right-hand side until finding the 'relevant cause' (ie. minimal failure case). It will be handy to [read a reference on ES6 destructuring rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Comment: It does work on other pages, and it works when declared within the function?

Comment: check using 'var' keyword instead of 'let'. because unlike 'var'(which defines a variable globally, or locally to an entire function regardless of block scope). If we declare a variable using 'let' outside a function then it does not find the value of that variable inside the function which is not bound to the function's scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Electron's `remote` is not normal javascript object, it constructs proxy object when it's being asked, and doesn't export all of proxy-able namespace in its module exports : check https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/3a79eacb6f44eadb6c17d725755d4278f62993dc/lib/renderer/api/remote.js#L297-L339 for internals.

Means, deconstruction in static import is not guaranteed. Reason wrapped function may work is it's proxy object is being constructed after application init stage, while top level doesn't - can't say for sure still as can't see full code flows though.

Any cases, may not try to deconstruct over proxy object.

Comment: Chosen as the write answer because it's informative. Thanks. I've since went with `electron.remote.app` where why `electron = require("electron")`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem in your code ist that you are trying to init an anonymous object in the outer most scope

```js
function require(){ /*require code goes here*/ }


let {  remote: { app  }  } = require('electron');
```

The last example of you works because the anonymous object is wrapped in a function thus its not in the outer most scope

```js
function require(){ /*require code goes here*/ }

let wrapperFunction = () => {
  let {  remote: { app  }  } = require('electron');
}

console.log("No errors or warnings");
```